# Function using get_posts() with tax_query not working when called from functions.php

Tags: wp-query, loop, get-posts, tax-query

I want to get an array of all the 'bands' in taxonomy 'types', and use the array later on in other functions etc. I have a `utilities.php` file that I `require()` in `functions.php` and it has the following function definition and a call to it right after:

```
function get_all_bands()
{
    $bands = get_posts(array(
        'post_type'      => 'model',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,

        // Includes the bands
        // NOTE: this wont work if this function is called from functions.php
        // which I need to do.
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'types',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'band',
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    ));
    return $bands;
}
print_r(get_all_bands())
```

If I `print_r(get_all_bands())` in a template like `header.php`, `page.php`, or in general any template that is charge of displaying stuff, it works fine. But if I `print_r(get_all_bands())` in `functions.php` it returns an empty array so I can't use it on anything.

Without the `tax_query` it works anywhere:

```
// This works
function get_all_bands()
{
    $bands = get_posts(array(
        'post_type'      => 'model',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    ));
    return $bands;
}
print_r(get_all_bands())
```

I've also tried to add the `global $post` into the function but it did nothing.

EDIT: clarifying where the functions are defined and called.

Comment: Either this function or the function where you are using this function in is hooked to a hook earlier than `init`

Comment: I'm assuming that this function is within `functions.php`? If so, where exactly are you declaring `print_r(get_all_bands())`? I believe if it's called too early the `tax_query` will not work, thus can I suggest using the `wp_loaded` hook to test the function. [Check here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) for all available hooks if you wish to find a more appropriate one.

Comment: @DavidGard I have this function in a `utilities.php` that I `require()` in `functions.php`. I call `print_r(get_all_bands())` right after I've defined it (just to test it, in reality I would use it in function somewhere).

Comment: @PieterGoosen the latter function without the `tax_query` works just fine.

Comment: @any_h Please reread your question and reread my first comment. You are trying to use a `tax_query` before the taxonomy is even set. Because of this, your `tax_query` fails. Add this at the beginning of your function `if( !taxonomy_exists( 'types' ) ) die();. If execution stops, your taxonomy does not exist yet, which means your function is running way to early

Answer (score 1):

For testing purposes in your `functions.php` file, try this -

```
add_action('init', 'my_test_get_all_bands', 99);
function my_test_get_all_bands(){
    echo '<pre>'; print_r(get_all_bands()); echo '<pre>';
}
```

As I was attempting to say in my comment to your question (and as **Pieter Goosen** explained rather better), if your taxonomies have not yet been registered then the `tax_query` portion of your `get_all_bands()` function will not work as the taxonomy `types` does not exist.

I don't know exactly how you are adding the taxonomy, but personally I use the `init` hook with a priority of `1`, and that is why I've used a priority of `99` in this example.

The long and short of it though is that your function works, you've proved that by using it in your templates :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm working on this tomorrow and I'll try to wrap my head around it somehow :)

Comment: This should be the correct answer! Worked for me.